# Set cookie if not exist, Update/override if exists in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I want to store the data of visited Blogs by the visitor. and I will show it to them in Recently Visited Blogs section.
For this functionality I have to use Cookies of course.

So I want to check if cookies exist or not, 
If it doesn't exist, a new cookie should create with a value of current Page's ID.
if it exist then my current page's ID should be added to the string in the cookie.

Below is my code which isn't working. 
PS: I have mentioned some of the things via comment

```
global $wp_query; //Its global variable in Wordpress

if(!isset($_COOKIE['recent_posts'])) {

    $cookie_value = $wp_query->post->ID; //this returns current page's ID

    setcookie('recent_posts', $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day

    $_COOKIE['recent_posts'] = $cookie_value;

    echo $_COOKIE['recent_posts'];
} 
else {

    $previous_cookie = $_COOKIE['recent_posts'];

    $current_cookie = $previous_cookie.','.$wp_query->post->ID;

    setcookie('recent_posts', $current_cookie, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
}
```

Comment: What specifically is not working? Secondly, what is the need of the `if` statement? It seems that you are doing the exact same thing, so why not just have a `setcookie` call without the if statements. Meaning, `if` the cookie does not exist, it will create it, if it does exist, it will overwrite it.

Comment: If block is executing but cookies is not getting created

Comment: Wrap your `setcookie` call in `print_r`, what does it output? Also (just in case): '[*Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie expires.*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)'

Comment: @Script47 I made a mistake. I had to use this code before HTML tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use cookies before get_header or use it in init action wordpress.